# Extracting number from the line of text if the number is not present make it null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have data which has a number which i need to extract the number is typically followed by **"sh-"** and should return a null if doesnt have any **'sh-'** in it.
   the sample of data i have is like this :

> *Tnsf from sh-849116 Act-13383.38 Unam-13383.38 04/12/12*
>
> *Tnsf from sh-849116 Act() Unam() 04/12/12*
>
> System added, to accommodate the fact that the commencement date was not at the beginning of a quarter.*Tnsf from sh-849116 Act() Unam() 04/12/12*
>
> RECLASSED PAYMENT IN SAP TO CAR WASH MATERIAL CODE.  COULDN'T DELETE FORECOURT PAYMENT SINCE IT WAS ALREADY PAID OUT.
>
> AMO CHANGE. SEE FILE. CAS 5.21.10*Tnsf from sh-849116 Act-12451.20 Unam-12451.20 04/12/12*

The output should be:

> 84916
>
> 84916
>
> 84916
>
> null
>
> 84916

Thanking you in advance

I have edited it

Comment: nope it doesnt return anything Abe!

Comment: *Typically preceded by* and *always preceded by* is a key distinction to make. Will the number you need to parse out **always** be preceded with `sh-` and followed by a space?

Comment: Abe I have corrected it, Yuck- yeah it always preceedes with sh-

Comment: You can do this using a mind numbing combination of `CHARINDEX`/`SUBSTRING`/`LEFT`/`RIGHT`, but I would suggest doing this in your code if possible.  If you can do it in code it will be much simpler/easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Declare @string nvarchar(250)

    select @string='Tnsf from sh-849116 Act-13383.38 Unam-13383.38 04/12/12'

     SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('sh-',@string)+3,6)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the number following the `sh-`:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(255) = 'Tnsf from sh-849116 Act-13383.38 Unam-13383.38 04/12/12'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX('sh-',@string)+3,CHARINDEX(' ',@string,CHARINDEX('sh-',@string))-CHARINDEX('sh-',@string)-3)
```

In your query I would add a `CASE` statement if `sh-` is not on every row:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('sh-',StringField) > 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(StringField,CHARINDEX('sh-',StringField)+3,CHARINDEX(' ',StringField,CHARINDEX('sh-',StringField))-CHARINDEX('sh-',StringField)-3)
       END
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: SQL State: 37000]  Function CHARINDEX invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).

Comment: The top query should work, the bottom one I had a typo, should be fixed.

Comment: Does the first query work properly for you?  I can't replicate a problem with it.

Comment: I use DBvisualizer might be thats the problem i am facing.

Comment: That could be, I'm not familiar with DBvisualizer.